# Angular2: Child routes

Tags: angular, routes

I have a home component that I would like to display at all times.  It is a dropdown menu.  When an item in the menu is clicked, a form pops up below.  I want the dropdown to display at all times.  Originally I designed it like this:

**my-app.html**

```
<div>
  <dropdown-selector></dropdown-selector>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The routing worked fine, but I kept getting `Error: Cannot match any routes: ''(…)` even though I have the `base` tag defined in my index.html.

Then I thought that I should define the dropdown as the parent route, and have all the dropdown item routes be its children.

**app-routes.ts** excerpt

```
export const APPLICATION_ROUTES: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: Home, // dropdown-selector is inside this component
        children: [
          {path: 'forms/1', component: Form1},
          {path: 'forms/2', component: Form2},
          {path: 'forms/3', component: Form3},
          {path: 'forms/4', component: Form4},
          {path: 'forms/5', component: Form5},
          {path: 'forms/6', component: Form6},
          {path: 'forms/7', component: Form7},
          {path: 'forms/8', component: Form8}
        ]
    }
];
```

And then redefine my-app.html...

**my-app.html**

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I keep getting the same error anyway, but now the dropdown won't even display.  Also, with the new router, I don't think there is a way to set a default route.  I was assuming that `''` was the default route.  I am using Angular2 RC.4.

Am I designing this the wrong way?  What's up with that error?  I saw a lot of SO posts addressing it, but none of them solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think your first design is what you want, as I have the same behavior on my solution :

I want my header and footer to be displayed all the time, and navigate through components in the middle of the page.

```
<headerComponent></headerComponent>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footerComponent></footerComponent>
```

---

Now to your main problem, which is

> Error: Cannot match any routes: ''(…)

I would need more code that shows how you navigate with your router, but I will give you the following hints :

It means that when you launch your app, the url looks like this :

```
http://localhost:39351/
```

and therefore the path is empty : ''

You need to define a route to manage that case as well (If you need to and I think you do not in this case).
For example, when I launch my app I want it to load a component by default, and I do it that way :

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

In your case, it seems that you want to display your form on a click and then access that route on the click. To do that, you need to manage the click like this in your dropdown-selector component Html :

```
<button type="button" (click)="navigate('btn_home')"> 
</button>
```

And then tell the router to navigate to your path :

```
navigate(elementID) {
       switch (elementID) {
                case 'btn_home':
                    this.router.navigate(['/master']);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
       }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked :), but I'd like to configure the `''` path to go to a "ghost" component.  I don't want anything to be displayed there.  I don't like the sound of that idea though.

Comment: In my own solution, I actually have a main <router-outlet> that manages the authentication, and then I have my second <router-outlet> (the one I pasted above) that manages the rest of the app.
In this case, you need to define the second outlet as a child of the first one. You should see the Angular2 documentation on routers to help you do that.
If this is an accepted answer, please mark it, I would really appreciate it. Do not hesitate to ask another question on another post if you need more help.